# What websites/forums should I go to for critique?

Tags: websites, critique

Are there any good sound design websites/forums for posting demo videos for critique that I should know about?

Thanks,

Ian.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the [chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13350/the-echo-chamber) here.  We can't handle them on the main site if you don't have a specific problem you are trying to fix, but chat is an ideal environment for critiques and general feedback on work.